# Is it possible to use the CSPROJ version when creating NuGet packages via gulp?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, gulp, nuget, csproj

I'm currently using a gulp file to create a NuGet package automatically whenever the project is built. One trouble I'm currently having is the versioning - ideally I'd like the NuGet package version to reflect the version of the project.

I've checked through various tools for gulp and node, but have so far been unable to find anything that might help. Has anyone come across a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, csproj file doesn’t have its own version. This file have information about the files included in that project, assemblies used in that project, project GUID and project version and so on.

So I assume you want to get the product/assembly version and then using this version as the NuGet package version. You could use gulp to read the file and then use regular expression to match the file version information.